# Call function if variable does not exist in a filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I'm doing filtering on a data displayed in a view which is working correctly. I've placed a filter bar at the top of the screen where a user can filter the records. What I want to achieve is when the variable the user enters is not found in the records a function should be called

```
 filterProducts(ev) {
    this.productService.list = this.reOrderList;
    const val = ev.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
      this.productService.list = this.reOrderList.filter((item) => {
        return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      });
    } else {
     // value doesn't exist console.log('call another function')
   }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the length of the filter result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if any items are left in the array after the filter is complete:

```
if (this.productService.list.length) {
  // The user's query was found in the array
} else {
  // The user's query was not found in the array
}
```